# Where can I run Atom command?

Tags: atom-editor

Please run Atom command '`Atom-Beautify: Migrate Settings`'.
You have unsupported `options: _analyticsUserId`

[image]

Comment: Please explain what you are trying to do. The image you added just shows the same error message you wrote

Comment: 'atom-beauty' has an analyticsUserId,but somehow my options of this isn't working.When I use  shortcut,atom always warns like that.I just don't unstand the hint "run Atom command ".

Answer (score 34, accepted):

**cmd + shift + p**
an then insert command without '

Answer (score 7):

This isn't very clear in Atom, but what you're after is this menu item: [Toggle Command Palette](https://github.com/atom/command-palette/blob/master/menus/command-palette.cson)

Mac OS X: Shift+Command+P:

[image: Mac OS X: Shift+Command+P]

Windows: Ctrl+Shift+P

[image: Windows: Ctrl+Shift+P]